# All the exceptions that can be thrown by JdbcTemplate.execute() method

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-jdbc

How can I find out which exceptions can be thrown by `JdbcTemplate.execute()` method call. I know it throws `DataAccessException`. But since `DataAccessException` is the parent class of actual exceptions that are thrown, that becomes a very broad statement.

For example, it throws `BadSqlGrammarException` which is the subclass. I know I can find it in source code, but I'd like to know if there's a list or some way to find it, plus inferring from the source code may cause problems. The reason is to catch exceptions so that I can log them and notify the user appropriately. So, how can I find out which exceptions are thrown, exactly? Should I do that or catching `DataAccessException` and logging its message is enough?

Comment: _"inferring from the source code may cause problems"_ How? Isn't the source code the best reference there is? It would be the first place I'd look if I had access to it.

Comment: Other options are looking for javadoc or other documentation, writing test cases that simulate possible errors, and looking at stacktraces.

Comment: The problem I meant wasn't like a catastrophic one, but I may think that I have covered all of them, but actually forget to look somewhere else. That type of issues. I have looked Spring API Documentation, but it states only `DataAccessException`. It shows the hierarchy, but I cannot know which exceptions are thrown exactly. There may be an exception which is under `DataAccessException` but not thrown by `execute()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the parent exception and use raw code or one of the utility libraries to get to the exception root cause. 
Raw code sample below, invoked from catch block.
Root cause of the exception and message should always be logged. Generally have a common exception handler centralized, to log exceptions only in one place ( example in Spring applications, we use **@ControllerAdvice**

```
private static Throwable findSpecificCause(Throwable throwable) {
        Throwable rootCause = getRootCause(throwable);
        return (rootCause != null ? rootCause : throwable);
    }

private static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Throwable rootCause = null;
        Throwable cause = throwable.getCause();
        while (cause != null && cause != rootCause) {
            rootCause = cause;
            cause = cause.getCause();
        }
        return rootCause;
    }
```

You can also consider using libraries like Apache's common lang ExceptionUtils, Spring NestedExceptionUtils or from Guava

Also see link :[Exception Root Cause](https://www.baeldung.com/java-exception-root-cause)

Comment: Thanks for the advice about Exception handling libraries, I didn't know them to be honest. I tried what you suggested, so far, I think it is what I was looking for. Also, I know **@ControllerAdvice**, however, I haven't used a `Controller` so far.